# Not able to reset "changed" flag - what am I doing wrong?

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to detect whether there have been changes in my application, and prompt the user to save if they leave before saving.  I am using angular's $watch function for this.  I am finding that when I reset the fields I'm watching, even if I reset the changed flag, it doesn't work.  Is it a race condition?

Here is the plunk - note that Save works, but after pressing New, it still shows that there are unsaved changes.

http://plnkr.co/edit/0EQpCarjVj5o2cb8TeNa?p=preview

js:

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.changed = false;

  $scope.$watch('[thing]', function(newValue, oldValue) {
    if (newValue != oldValue) {
      $scope.changed = true;
    }
  }, true);

  $scope.saveClicked = function() {
    // save the data somewhere
    $scope.changed = false;  // this works!
  };

  $scope.newClicked = function() {
    $scope.thing = {};
    $scope.changed = false;  // this doesn't work!
  };
});
```

html:

```
  <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <form id=f>
    <input type=text name=t1 ng-model=thing.t1>
    <input type=text name=t2 ng-model=thing.t2>
    <button ng-click="saveClicked()">Save</button>
    <button ng-click="newClicked()">New</button>
    </form>
    <br>
    <span ng-show="changed">You have unsaved changes!</span>
    <span ng-show="!changed">All changes have been saved.</span>
  </body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that because of how `$watch` works this actually runs *after* `$scope.changed = false` so it ends up being set to true again.

There are several possible solutions for this, but one would be to check for a default condition instead.  For example:

```
$scope.changed = false;
$scope.thing = null;
$scope.$watch('thing', function(newValue, oldValue) {
  // Default value means the form is now clean
  if (newValue == null) {
    return;

// Also set to null when `New` is clicked.
```